# Mapping JPA for DB2 Spatial

Tags: hibernate, jpa, db2, openjpa, websphere-7

I am currently working on an application based on WebSphere Application Server 7 and DB2 Spatial Extender and I'd like to use JPA for the data access layer.

I've set up a very simple table in my Database for testing purpose:

```
JMTEST (id integer | position db2gse.st_point)
```

The challenge is to map the **position** column (db2gse.st_point) to a field of my JPA Entity

The only working solution I found so far is to use Hibernate as the JPA implementation so that I can make use of the @ColumnTransformer annotation:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "getAllRecords", query = "SELECT j FROM Jmtest j")
public class Jmtest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ColumnTransformer(read="db2gse.ST_AsText(position)",write="db2gse.ST_PointFromText(?,1003)")
    private String position;
```

Since I am using WebSphere 7, it comes with JPA 1.0 and the IBM or the OpenJPA implementation.
Unfortunately, I am afraid I will have to stick to these (no possibility to use JPA 2.0 neither to use an alternate JPA provider)

I could not find the equivalent of @ColumnTransformer in the IBM or OpenJPA implementations. If it exists, could someone please explain to me what I should use?

If it does not, could you please give me some advice on how I can map a DB2Spatial column to a JPA entity field using the IBM/OpenJPA implementation?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `@Factory` and `@Externalizer` annotations that exist in [OpenJPA](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual.html#ref_guide_pc_extern).

Comment: I did, but it does not seem to meet my needs. Indeed, the field transformation is performed by a java method whereas in my case the transformation can only be made by a specific DB2Spatial SQL function (db2gse.ST_AsText and db2gse.ST_PointFromText)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not bound to JPA 1. You can install a [feature pack](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/osgi/) for getting JPA 2 support.

Afterwards you can configure WAS to use a [third party jpa provider](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.jpafep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftejb_jpa3rdparty.html) like Hibernate.

Using the third party provider also works without the feature pack, however you are bound to old versions that use jpa 1 then.

Comment: Yes you are right, I am aware that I could install the Feature Pack for JPA 2. But as I said, I'd prefer to avoid it because I am not sure it won't interfere with the other applications already installed on the WAS and making use of the out of the box JPA1 implementation (OpenJPA).

I was able to use Hibernate as a JPA1 provider on WAS7 (without the FeaturePack), but since the JPA1 compatible Hibernate version is quite old, the @ColumnTransformer annotation is not there. I still can't find any equivalent with OpenJPA

Comment: Well, actually we are using JPA 2 on WAS 7 without the feature pack. A work around is using Spring(we use it anyway) and load JPA via spring, if you give your persistence.xml a different name WAS won't pick it up and you can load it via Spring with persistenceXMLLocation (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setPersistenceXmlLocation%28java.lang.String%29) beeing set.